How can I remove a change(s) in a previous git commit's history?
I have 3 changes in a commit called B. The changes are C1, C2 and C3 for brevity. My pull request has commits A -> B -> C -> D -> E. I would like to completely remove the changes (deletions) C3 from commit B because that was a mistake.
I tried the following.

git rebase -i <SHA for Commit A for last commit before Commit B>
git show path/to/file to see the changes in the file
git show path/to/file | git apply -R
git add path/to/file
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git push -f

Instead of undoing the deletions from the file, the git history is showing that I still made the deletions, but then added the deleted entries. Is there a way to remove the deletion completely from the git history, or is this simply how git works?

During your interactive rebase, set the commit you want to change as "edit" https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits. When it gets to that point in the rebase, you should see all your pending changes in that commit as changed (may or may not be staged, I forget). You can then do your edits on that set of changes, and when ready, git commit and git rebase --continue to finish. If your branch is off of main, do git rebase -i main while the branch you want to rebase is checked out.

I tried that, but the diffs are still showing up when I try "git show /path/to/file". Is there a way to erase that change altogether? I am expecting that when I try "git show /path/to/file", I will see that there are no diffs. Basically, I want it to be as if I didn't even touch the file. I tried "git reset path/to/file" and "git restore --staged path/to/file", but they didn't undo the changes. I would like to qualify that the changes themselves in the file are reversed. I'm just trying to rewrite git history so that its like the changes to the file didn't occur. Is that possible?

To figure out what commit(s) brought what changes to path/to/file, use:
git log --graph -p -- path/to/file


The sequence of actions you mention (1 to 6) is a correct way to edit changes in a past commit, you may add the following checks:

make sure that you placed the edit action on the commits you expect,
after step 4 git add path/to/file, you may run git diff HEAD~ path/to/file, to check that there are indeed no changes anymore wrt the previous commit,
after step 5 git commit --amend, you may run git show --name-only to double check that path/to/file does not show up (meaning: no modification was brought to that file in that commit)


I've done this, and git history shows that I've made changes and then changed them back, which equates to no changes to the file. However, I am expecting that no changes are being shown to the file. Is there a way of getting rid of this in git commit history?

@JuanBustamante : please update your questino with the current output of git log --graph --oneline --name-status -- path/to/file, and indicate which commit contains the changes and which commit contains the revert

I've ended up doing git reset then restore, and then checkout to replace the file. I've put the details in my response below.

I ended up doing the following to fix this.

git rebase -i <SHA for Commit A for last commit before Commit B>
git reset --soft HEAD~
git restore --staged path/to/file <-- unstage the file
git checkout -- path/to/file <-- replace the changes/deletions made
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git push -f

